# Disable mouse acceleration on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, input-device, mouse

I can't figure out how to change the mouse acceleration setting such that the change is persistent. Changing the value in the Preferences > Keyboard and mouse settings keeps resetting every time I open it (back to Acceleration: 5). A physical test shows that there is still acceleration as I move the mouse a constant distance quickly then slowly, even though xinput properties says acceleration is 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is it possible that you have more than one mouse defined?